# How can I run iPhone simulator over full-screen(lion) Xcode 4.1?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

I love to work with full-screen mode Xcode, but there's one inconvenience,

If I run iPhone simulator, it is shown in other space.

Is there any way to run iPhone simulator over full-screen Xcode?

If then, I can work with happiness really!

Comment: not that I know of, but if you are running a dual monitor setup, then it won't affect you anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others point out, Apple doesn't allow to run two full screen apps one over the other one. However, you could put them next to each other like this which already is an enhancement (at least for me):

[image]

I use VS Code instead of Xcode but the logic is the same. All you have to do is just to allow iOS Simulator to run in Full Screen by running the following command in terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator AllowFullscreenMode -bool YES
```

Comment: Thanks for all community helps for ~10 years! I don't work with Xcode and iPhone simulator anymore, but I think this is reasonable solution for now so put as accepted solution.

Comment: Happy to help :) Thanks for accepting this as the solution :)

Answer (score 14):

There doesn't seem to be any way to do this.  I think part of the idea of having a full-screen mode is that you *cannot* have any other windows open on top of the full-screen window.

Try opening Xcode in full-screen mode, then open the organizer window, and you'll see what I mean. The organizer opens in its *own* full-screen mode space.

Which makes sense, even though it's inconvenient in this case.  I think if Apple were to give the iOS simulator its own full-screen mode, that would be nicer than just throwing it up on a desktop.

It seems like the ideal solution would be for Apple to integrate the iOS simulator into the Xcode debugging environment, similar to what they did with Interface Builder in Xcode 4.

Comment: Like most of this response, so +1 but definite -1 to having the simulator integrated into the Xcode environment, if you mean that it wouldn't have its own window. Just for the functionality of being able to easily take 'screenshots' with Cmd-Shift-4 then Spacebar that are a snapshot of the iPhone outline with the app displayed on it alone is a reason to keep it as a separate window. :)

Comment: That's true, though I don't know why you couldn't still take screenshots of the app if it were running inside an Xcode window.

Comment: I find this a big deficiency in Xcode 4, and more generally with Lion full screen. My two monitor setup makes full screen a waste most of the time. I wish I could have one app _per screen_.

Dual monitors aside, not being able to see the simulator at the same time as your Xcode working window seems like a **huge** limitation - why bother using full screen at all?

Apple should either integrate the simulator into Xcode (I'd like it, but I can see where it might be a bad idea), or let users do one app per monitor.  Better yet, both.

Comment: agree with Stephan - and I'm betting that a) many devs at Apple have dual monitors, and b) that that they think this limitation sucks too and that c) therefore apple will soon support this - though not soon enough. Hence -1 for trying to justify an obvious limitation - don't apologize for them!

Comment: 18 months later, this is still infuriating. Every Xcode point release I scan release notes for this addition. Every time disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

To run simulators in full-screen mode, you need to enable fullscreen mode by executing the following command in your terminal:

> `defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator AllowFullscreenMode -bool YES`

*You need to restart the simulator in order to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, you can now do this as of Xcode 9. You need to enable the Internal menu in iOS Simulator.

To do this:

1. Create the folder `AppleInternal` in the root directory: `sudo mkdir /AppleInternal`
2. Restart all instances of the iOS Simulator.
3. Observe the available Internal menu, navigate to `Internal | Allow Fullscreen Mode` and ensure this option is ticked.

After following these steps, you can enable fullscreen mode on the iOS simulator.

Information taken from: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/simulator-on-steroids-c12774ca6b

Comment: `sudo mkdir /AppleInternal` doesn't work: at root level you are not allowed to create a directory with that name or to rename a directory AppleInternal. (`mkdir: /AppleInternal: Operation not permitted`).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going with [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12#) or something similar.  Then you can easily size the window to take up the full screen without losing the use of a second monitor or the ability to see Xcode and the simulator as you're debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer this question, but it's worth noting that under Xcode 4.6 at least the Organizer window will open on a second screen even if Xcode is running full-screen.

Also, I highly recommend Dash as a documentation viewer, as this can be set to 'HUD' window mode, and therefore be visible on a second monitor even when Xcode is full screen.

Still want to know how to do this with the Simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Debug Workflow in Xcode to "Xcode Always Behind". When you are coding you can use full screen mode, when you are debugging, you will see Xcode in the background.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if anyone is still looking, but the best way is to use Xcode behaviors. In the Running section, under Starts, select Exit Full Screen. Then under Completes, select Enter Full Screen. Works great!

Comment: Is "Exit Full Screen" still available in Behaviors for Xcode 6? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is (in your simulator) go to  `window/stay In Front`. Just like this

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It appears this has been removed as of XCode 9.  
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245154/151980

Answer (score 0):

1. Shut down your Mac,
2. Boot into the Recovery Mode, When shut, start pressing **CMD + R** and while still pressing power up your machine and keep pressing the button combination until the Apple logo appears so that your Mac boots into the Recovery Mode.
3. Click **Utilites** and choose **Terminal**
4. Type `diskutil list` and identify the id of your disk named Macintosh HD, it should be something like `/dev/disk2s1`
5. Now we need to mount it: type `diskutil mount /dev/[YOUR_DISK_ID]`. If successful, keep going with the next step. If not, you probably got a message regarding APFS that the disk needs to be unlocked, so type `diskutil apfs unlockVolume /dev/[YOUR_DISK_ID]`
6. Finally you can create the required folder to enable hidden Xcode features: type `mkdir /Volumes/[YOUR_MAC_DRIVE_NAME]/AppleInternal`
   Now you can get out of the Recovery Mode and boot your Mac as usual.
   Open and run your project on simulator. Now you can see a new bar menu item named **Internal**. There is an option to set simulator to fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Big Sur this is now supported, so you just go full screen with the Simulator window or drag it into split view as you would with any other window.